# Android - ToyVPN Is it possible to "fake" VPN connection?

Tags: android, vpn

I'm working on an app and I've figured out I need to setup a VPN service and everything for it to work for what I need it to. However, I don't have VPN server and I don't need one. I just need app to think it's connected to the VPN.

Purpose of this is to block or allow network for other apps. Apps that are allowed through VPN won't get any network, as VPN is not actually working.

I've managed to setup ToyVPN from android developers as an example, but not sure what I need to do next in order to make it think it's connected to VPN, while having just a dummy connection or nothing at all.

Thanks for responses in advance!

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.